# Fail to query via move_pages()

Tags: c++, linux, numa

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numaif.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const constexpr uint64_t size = 16lu * 1024 * 1024;
    const constexpr uint32_t nPages = size / (4lu * 1024 * 1024);
    int32_t status[nPages];
    std::fill_n(status, nPages, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min());
    void* pages[nPages];

    auto fd = shm_open("test_shm", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
    void* ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        if (fd > 0) close(fd);
        throw "failed to map hugepages";
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nPages; i++) {
        pages[i] = (char*)ptr + 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    }

    if (0 != move_pages(0, nPages, pages, nullptr, status, 0)) {
        std::cout << "failed to inquiry pages because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nPages; i++) {
            std::cout << "page # " << i << " locates at numa node " << status[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    munmap(ptr, size);
    close(fd);
}
```

And it prints:

> ```
> page # 0 locates at numa node -2
> page # 1 locates at numa node -2
> page # 2 locates at numa node -2
> page # 3 locates at numa node -2
> ```

According to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/move_pages), it states:

> ```
> nodes is an array of integers that specify the desired location for each page.
> Each element in the array is a node number. nodes can also be NULL, in which 
> case move_pages() does not move any pages but instead will return the node where 
> each page currently resides, in the status array. Obtaining the status of each 
> page may be necessary to determine pages that need to be moved.
> ```

Why does it print negative values although querying return success?  My machine only has 2 NUMAs -- 0 and 1.

kernel version: 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64

Here is the version for hugepages:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numaif.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        const int32_t dst_node = strtoul(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
        const constexpr uint64_t size = 4lu * 1024 * 1024;
        const constexpr uint64_t pageSize = 2lu * 1024 * 1024;
        const constexpr uint32_t nPages = size / pageSize;
        int32_t status[nPages];
        std::fill_n(status, nPages, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min());
        void* pages[nPages];
        int32_t dst_nodes[nPages];
        void* ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);

        if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
                throw "failed to map hugepages";
        }
        memset(ptr, 0x41, nPages*pageSize);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nPages; i++) {
                pages[i] = &((char*)ptr)[i*pageSize];
                dst_nodes[i] = dst_node;
        }

        std::cout << "Before moving" << std::endl;

        if (0 != move_pages(0, nPages, pages, nullptr, status, 0)) {
            std::cout << "failed to inquiry pages because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        }
        else {
                for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nPages; i++) {
                        std::cout << "page # " << i << " locates at numa node " << status[i] << std::endl;
                }
        }

        // real move
        if (0 != move_pages(0, nPages, pages, dst_nodes, status, MPOL_MF_MOVE_ALL)) {
                std::cout << "failed to move pages because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
        }

        const constexpr uint64_t smallPageSize = 4lu * 1024;
        const constexpr uint32_t nSmallPages = size / smallPageSize;
        void* smallPages[nSmallPages];
        int32_t smallStatus[nSmallPages] = {std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min()};
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nSmallPages; i++) {
                smallPages[i] = &((char*)ptr)[i*smallPageSize];
        }


        std::cout << "after moving" << std::endl;
        if (0 != move_pages(0, nSmallPages, smallPages, nullptr, smallStatus, 0)) {
            std::cout << "failed to inquiry pages because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        }
        else {
                for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nSmallPages; i++) {
                        std::cout << "page # " << i << " locates at numa node " << smallStatus[i] << std::endl;
                }
        }

}
```

The interesting thing is that `move_pages()` seems to understand hugepages as after the hugepages are moved, I query based on small page size, and it populates the expected NUMA IDs.

Comment: Why do you pass incorrect number of pages to `move_pages`?  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/move_pages.2.html "count is the number of pages to move.  It defines the size of the three arrays pages, nodes, and status." (enjoying current quality of open-source documentation). The only correct docs are the sources: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/mm/migrate.c#L1367  and I see no handling of huge pages. Why do you think that shm mmaped memory will be backed by huge pages?

Comment: @osgx I actually tried to simplified the problem by removing hugepages from the picture.

Comment: actually your call of move_pages is incorrect in 3rd argument "pages" - you give single pointer to memory, but it should be list of pages (check the code in my updated answer). All kernel API are for standard "small" pages; and move_pages on hugepages is another problem. Please give full example with hugepages and with correct pages array for move_pages call.

Comment: And for your updated code with -2: command `errno 2` from moreutils says "ENOENT" and man pages says "The page is not present.". Do access every page for write to fault it from zero page to real page. Zero page has no numa status, only real pages do have.

Comment: @osgx thanks for your detailed explanation.  2 more questions: 1.  you mentioned all kernel APIs are for standard "small" pages, then should I populate `pages` based on "small" pages size (e.g. 2MB hugepages will have 2MB/4KB pointers in `pages`)?  2. Does read fault the page?  Or only write can fault the page?  Thanks!

Comment: @osgx added example for hugepage.  It seems like `move_pages()` understands hugepages?

Comment: When kernel API says page it is small page. When API has any additional support for huge page it probably will say about it (if documented correctly). Read may not prefault page - zero page may have read permission and will return zeroes (there may be even zero hugepage). Writes almost always will fault page, i think. For hugepages there are several methods to allocate and they may work differently. move_pages does understand hugepages for getting status, but the complex question is which hugepages can be numa moved (MPOL_MF_MOVE). Do we need new question posted?

Comment: @osgx [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726288/using-move-pages-to-move-hugepages).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of shm_open and mmap probably will not get huge pages as you want.

`move_pages` syscall (and libnuma wrapper) works on standard pages of 4096 bytes for x86_64.

And you use `move_pages` in wrong way with incorrect 3rd argument "pages". It should be not pointer to memory; but pointer to array which itself will contain nPages pointers:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/move_pages.2.html

```
  long move_pages(int pid, unsigned long count, void **pages,
                   const int *nodes, int *status, int flags);

   pages is an array of pointers to the pages that should be moved.
   These are pointers that should be aligned to page boundaries.
   Addresses are specified as seen by the process specified by pid.
```

Without correct pointers in the "pages' you will get  -14  which is EFAULT according to `errno 14` (from moreutils package).

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546367/fail-to-query-via-move-pages
//g++ 54546367.move_pages.cc -o 54546367.move_pages -lnuma -lrt
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numaif.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const constexpr uint64_t size = 256lu * 1024;// * 1024;
    const constexpr uint32_t nPages = size / (4lu * 1024);
    void * pages[nPages];
    int32_t status[nPages];
    std::fill_n(status, nPages, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min());

//  auto fd = shm_open("test_shm", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
//  void* ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    void* ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Ptr is " << ptr << std::endl;
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
//      if (fd > 0) close(fd);
        throw "failed to map hugepages";
    }
    memset(ptr, 0x41, nPages*4096);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<nPages; i++) {
        pages[i] = &((char*)ptr)[i*4096];
    }

    if (0 != move_pages(0, nPages, pages, nullptr, status, 0)) {
        std::cout << "failed to inquiry pages because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nPages; i++) {
            std::cout << "page # " << i << " locates at numa node " << status[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    munmap(ptr, size);
//  close(fd);
}
```

With NUMA machine it outputs same node when started as `taskset -c 7 ./54546367.move_pages` and interleaved (0 1 0 1) when `numactl -i all ./54546367.move_pages`.

Comment: sorry.  too rush to code w/o checking.  fixed.  but still have -2..

Comment: My variant of code when started for large count of nPages (16MB of mem) has THP activated for `numactl -i all`: some pages at beginning has interleaved one by one (0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1), then large series of 00...00 and 11..11 for transparent huge pages, then one by one at the end. And I also did fault all pages (access every of them with write).