# Is unmap_and_move_huge_page() splits huge page into small pages?

Tags: memory-management, kernel

In source code of `migrate_pages()`, it will use `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` to migrate huge page

```
int migrate_pages(struct list_head *from, new_page_t get_new_page,
        free_page_t put_new_page, unsigned long private,
        enum migrate_mode mode, int reason, unsigned int *ret_succeeded)
{
    .......
  if (PageHuge(page))
    rc = unmap_and_move_huge_page(get_new_page,put_new_page, private, page,
                  pass > 2, mode, reason, &ret_pages);
  else
    rc = unmap_and_move(get_new_page, put_new_page, private, page, pass > 2, mode,
                  reason, &ret_pages);
       ......
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` splits huge page into small pages?(just like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726288/using-move-pages-to-move-hugepages/59730331#59730331) said)
2. if `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` will split huge page into small pages, which function does it call ?

All these functions are in Linux kernel 5.16. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

No, `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` will not split pages. If `PageHuge()` returns true (so when `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` is called), we know that the page was allocated by hugetlbfs (see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.20/source/mm/hugetlb.c#L1836). Allocated hugetlbfs pages will never be split.

The answer you're referring to is about transparent huge pages which is different from hugetlbfs. But `PageHuge()` will return 0 for these pages, therefore `unmap_and_move_huge_page()` will not be called.